# Vue.js - created() for dynamic drop-down

Tags: vue.js

I have a dynamic drop-down of select field that transfer params to another data.

```
<v-select 
  v-model="position.department_id"
  :items="departments" 
  item-text="department_name" 
  item-value="id" 
  label="Department"
  placeholder=" "
  @change='getSections()'
></v-select>
<v-select 
  v-model="position.section_id"
  :items="sections" 
  item-text="section_name" 
  item-value="id" 
  label="Section"
></v-select>

getSections () {
  axios.get('/api/sections', {
    params: { id: this.position.department_id }
  })
  .then(response => this.sections = response.data)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
},
```

It works when entering new data. Now the problem comes when I want to fetch / edit and display the data.

```
created () {
      this.getDepartments ()
      this.getSections ()
    },
```

As far as I know, `created ()` doesn't follow arrangement and instead load all functions at the same time. Since `sections` is dependable with the `id` of `departments`, the select section is not fetched. Is there like a way to delay a certain function to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to move your getSections() function after you fetched your departmens inside getDepartments method. see code below

```
created() {
   this.getDepartments()
}
```

then in your getDepartments function call the function getSections, like this

```
methods: {
    getDepartments() {
       axios.get('/getDepartments').then(({data}) => {
            this.getSections()
        })
    } 
}
```

Comment: I see how this goes, I'll make it work. Thank you very much!